# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MemoryPool'. .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Getting following error

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
> Object name: 'MemoryPool'. while reading requestBody from middleware.

Reading request body as follows

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
{
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}
```

Error comes completely randomly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading request body in middleware for .Net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768912/reading-request-body-in-middleware-for-net-5)

Comment: StreamReader will dispose the stream its reading when itself gets disposed by default. The constructor of StreamReader has a leaveOpen Parameter you should set to true.

Comment: And be aware that reading the body multiple times is a performance problem. Only do it for very good reasons unsolvable otherwise.

Comment: @Ralf we are doing it for 2 different kinds of logging. One we are logging from ExceptionFilter and other from Middleware, need requestBody at both places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `leaveOpen` parameter to the `StreamReader`:

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
{
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}
```

Also note that perfromance-wise reading request multiple times can have detrimental effect. And check out build-in [`HttpLoggingMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/39564d529f84f7a3bbac5b28ba11060e8ac30375/src/Middleware/HttpLogging/src/HttpLoggingMiddleware.cs#L56) for some inspirations which also reads the request body.